# Assertion failure in UICollectionView when trying to reload data

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uicollectionview

I get an Error:

```
    Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData numberOfItemsBeforeSection:],/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionViewData.m


    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for number of items before section 2 when there are only 1 sections in the collection view'
```

when i try to reload the collectionview.It works when new sections are added but when i try to remove them it throws an exception.

update:

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return object.count;
```

}

```
 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
if([sortString isEqualToString:@"title"])
    return [Obj.ordered allKeys].count;
else
    return 1;
```

}

Comment: You'll have to show us the datasource delegate methods so we can see where the bug is.

Comment: added the delegates as update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before** deleting rows or sections, you have to delete items from your **data source** array. If your method returns `1` before deleting section then after deleting it should return `0`.

Comment: but when reloading the collectionview i think it will be handled by the app ryt?

Comment: Reloading the collection view is just reloading the UI. You have to take care of the data source. What you are doing is you tell the collection view draw 2 sections, then she asks the data source to give her stuff for section 2 and the data source says - well, I don't have it and crashes.

Comment: so i have to delete the sections before reloading?

Comment: Delete the items from your data source. Then reload collection view. The `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` method should return `1` before deleting the section and `0` after you deleted it.

Comment: wat i have done is made the data source to nil loaded it with new data and then reloaded the collectionview.then checked the delegate numberOfSectionsInCollectionView it returns 1.